Series, SeriesData, Approximate Numbers, and Precision Tracking
One of the features of Mathematica is the capability of doing arbitrary precision arithmetic and precision tracking. Mathematica has a build in command Series -- which produces a SeriesData object; Series is declared to be able to work with approximate numbers according to the documentation. Now my question concerns these two aspects and, to my understanding, some unexpected result. Say I create a Series (from SeriesData) with approximate numbers and some coefficients are zeros with certain accuracy, say 20 digits, meaning:
{N[π, 20], 0``20, 0``20, N[Log[2], 20]};
series1 = SeriesData[x, 0, %, 0, 4, 1]

Then everything is as expected
series1 
(* 3.1415926535897932385+0.69314718055994530942 x^3+O[x]^4 *)
series1 // InputForm
(* SeriesData[x, 0, {3.1415926535897932384626433832795028845`20., 0``20., 0``20., 0.69314718055994530941723212145817656807`20.}, 0, 4, 1] *)

I now created another Series with coefficients of 30 digits
N[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 30];
series2 = SeriesData[x, 0, %, 0, 4, 1];

I subtract the two series and everything is again as expected; I obtain a new series where the coefficients have 20 digits precision (the precision tracking works)
series1-series2
(* 2.1415926535897932385-2.0000000000000000000 x-3.0000000000000000000 x^2-3.30685281944005469058 x^3+O[x]^4 *)

I create now a third Series (I just reshuffle the coefficients of series1 putting the zeros with accuracy of 20 digits in the first positions, and specify that the series starts from the constant term)
{0``20, 0``20, N[π, 20], N[Log[2], 20]};
series3 = SeriesData[x, 0, %, 0, 4, 1]

In this case Mathematica deliberately rounds the first two coefficients to zero
series3 
(* 3.1415926535897932385 x^2+0.69314718055994530942 x^3+O[x]^4 *)
series3 // InputForm
(* SeriesData[x, 0, {3.1415926535897932384626433832795028845`20., 0.69314718055994530941723212145817656807`20.}, 2, 4, 1] *)

Clearly now series2-series3 will not track the precision.
If I work with lists, the the precision tracker works as expected, e.g.:
list1 = {0``20*x, N[x^2*π, 20]};
list2 = N[{2*x, x^2*Log[2]}, 30];
list1 - list2

Gives
(* {-2.0000000000000000000 x, 2.4484454730298479290 x^2} *)

Why does Mathematica discard those zeros coefficients in series3 (despite the fact I force the series to start from the constant term)?

Approximate spelling in title...

A leading term in a SeriesData object needs to be invertible. No type of zero is invertible.

SeriesData is designed for handling Taylor Expansion of functions. I don't see your goal, but SeriesData is not suitable for Precision Tracking.
